# How much research, approximately, is done in ANNs?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, research

Does someone know where can I find information about how much research, nowadays, is done in ANNs?

I've checked in this document [Redes Neuronales: Conceptos básicos y aplicaciones](https://www.frro.utn.edu.ar/repositorio/catedras/quimica/5_anio/orientadora1/monograias/matich-redesneuronales.pdf), Universidad Tecnológica Nacional, México (2001) by D. J. Matich, that "nowadays research is uncountable" but that was in 2001.

I found nothing else on my further google search. Then, I've consulted Google Scholar, and by clicking on the option "Since 2021" it displayed 38,800 results, but, AFAIK, it includes a lot of different types of documents, e.g. books.

Comment: I've no idea but checking the proceedings of top AI/ML conferences such as NeurIPS, ICML, ICLR, AAAI, IJCAI etc. might be useful.

Comment: @SpiderRico Oh ok, thanks.